# Export contents of section to .txt

Tags: export

Consider the following pseudocode:

```
\documentclass{article}%

\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{enumitem}%

% BASIC QUALIFICATIONS
\listadd\qualifications{A degree}%
\listadd\qualifications{Skill}%
\listadd\qualifications{Common sense}%
\listadd\qualifications{Enthusiasm}%

\begin{document}

% duties
\section*{Basic Qualifications}

% opening call for function which facilitates export of section (or subsection) contents
% <here>
% \begin{export}[include section title=true]{qualifications.txt}


The successful candidate will have the following basic qualifications:

\begin{itemize}[topsep=2mm]
\forlistloop{\item}{\qualifications}
\end{itemize}

% closing call for
% \end{export}

\end{document}
```

The goal is to export the contents of a `section` (or `subsection`, `subsubsection`, etc.) to a `.txt` file without markup.  Any suggestions as to the appropriate starting point are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

TeX4ht can slice the generated HTML to separate HTML files for each section or subsection. These HTML files can then be converted to TXT using `w3m` or other text based browser.

To automate this, you can use the following Lua build script:

```lua
local domfilter = require "make4ht-domfilter"
local mkutils = require "mkutils"
local process = domfilter {
function(dom)
  for _, crosslinks in ipairs(dom:query_selector(".crosslinks")) do
    crosslinks:remove_node()
  end
  return dom
end
}

Make:match("html$", process)
Make:match("html", function(filename, settings)
  local output_name = filename:gsub("html$", "txt")
  mkutils.execute("w3m -dump " .. filename .. " > " .. output_name)
end)
```

It removes links to previous and next file that TeX4ht inserts automatically and converts each HTML file to TXT using `w3m`.

Compile your file using:

```
make4ht -e build.lua main.tex "3,sec-filename"
```

It will produce two TXT files, "sample.txt" and "BasicQualifications.txt". Names of files for sections are based on section titles. "sample.txt" contains just table of contents. "BasicQualifications.txt" looks like this:

```
Basic Qualifications

The successful candidate will have the following basic qualifications:

  * A degree
  * Skill
  * Common sense
  * Enthusiasm
```